# MemSet & MemCopy

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, memcpy, memset

I'm writing a memory allocator, and I need a way to store an integer inside of a chunk of memory.  This integer will represent the size of the block so I can navigate to the end given the pointer to the beginning.

Here's my test example:

// EDIT: Declared space for testInt
    int* testInt = new int;

```
head_ptr = (char*) malloc(4*1024*1024); // Allocate 4MB

// EDIT: Should have used std::fill and std::copy
memset(head_ptr,23,sizeof(int)); // Set Address head_ptr = 12345

memcpy(testInt,head_ptr,sizeof(int)); // Set testInt = head_ptr

printf("testInt = %i",testInt);
```

This throws a segmentation fault on the second to last line.

Does what I'm trying to do make sense?

If so, what is the correct approach?

**Thank you so much everyone for your help!! Problem solved :-)**

Comment: Where is testInt being defined? That seems like the error here, not anything to do with head_ptr.

Comment: Since testInt does point anywhere reliable, the memcpy() doesn't work.  You need to print *testInt - and you need to initialize it: `int i; int *testInt = &i;`.

Comment: Is 12345 the value or the pointer to the value??

Comment: @Jonathin you make a good point but I still receive a Seg fault

Comment: @jpyllman it is the value, I have lowered it now so that it won't overflow

Comment: An overflow should not cause a segfault. Nor is the memset call failing here.

Comment: OK, the code you have now use an uninitialized pointer testInt into the memcpy() call. So you do not know where you copy the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer to original question

```
memset(head_ptr,12345,sizeof(int)); // Set Address head_ptr = 12345
```

No it doesn't. This sets the first `sizeof(int)` bytes of `head_ptr` to 12345, which will overflow (unless you are using an architecture where a byte is more than 8 bits).

```
memcpy(testInt,head_ptr,sizeof(int)); // Set testInt = head_ptr
```

What is testInt? An int*? An int? In the latter case use &testInt.

Also it appears from your tags that you are using C++ rather than C. But your code is really just C, you should really use the safer C++ functions and features:

- memset -> std::fill
- memcpy -> std::copy
- malloc -> new
- printf -> cout or (better) [Boost::Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/format/index.html)

### Answer to your edit

`int* testInt;` is a pointer to an integer variable but it's not initialized: it will point to a random memory area (we can consider it "random" for all intent and purposes even if it isn't).

`memcpy` will then try to write to this random memory area to which most likely you don't have access to, and therefore this results in a segmentation fault (that means "you can't access this memory area").

Comment: Thank you Andreas, I am much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

You've never initialized testInt, so your memcpy call is writing to who knows where.

Try this:

int *testInt = malloc(sizeof(int));

Answer (score 2):

Others commented on improper usage of `memset(3)` and `memcpy(3)`, so I'll reply to the allocator issue.

If you are really in the business of building custom memory allocator in C++ - take a look at Chapter 4 in Alexandrescu's [Modern C++ Design](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Main.ModernCDesign). It walks you through implementing small object allocator in detail. The code is available as part of the [Loki Library](http://loki-lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/loki-lib/loki/include/loki/SmallObj.h?view=markup).

Man, somebody likes unicorns ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see what `testInt` is I can't be sure, but my psychic debugging powers are indicating that you need to take the address of `testInt` rather than `testInt` itself as the argument to `memcpy`.

**EDIT:** Upon seeing what you've posted now, you need to allocate memory for `testInt` before using it.

Answer (score 1):

If testInt is just an "int", could it be since you're passing it by value, and it's not getting changed?